# Can you add comments to an append-only field in a list in Sharepoint 2010 using C#?

Tags: 2010, development, custom-list, splistitem, version-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you programmatically add comments to an append-only comment field in a custom item list using C#?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42442/can-you-programmatically-add-comments-to-an-append-only-comment-field-in-a-custo)

Posted on stack exchange first, then I found this Sharepoint sub-domain of stack exchange (n00bie).

Here's my post there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696325/can-you-programmatically-add-comments-to-an-append-only-comment-field-in-a-custo/11696414#comment15511133_11696414

For those that don't want to follow the link:

I understand that you can access comments in an append-only field like:

```
public string retrieveComments(SPListItem item) 
{ 
    SPListItemVersionCollection versions = item.Versions; 
    string latestComment = ""; 

    try 
    { 
        foreach (SPListItemVersion itemVersion in versions) 
        { 
            if (itemVersion.IsCurrentVersion) 
            { 
                latestComment = itemVersion["Comments"].ToString().Trim(); 

            } 
        } 
    } 
    catch (Exception e3) 
    { 
        //handles exception 
    } 

    return latestComment; 
}
```

Is there any way to create a new version of the list item and append a comment as the latest comment through C#?

My goal is for someone to email the list and take the body of their email and append it as a comment.