# Can you programmatically add comments to an append-only comment field in a custom item list using C#?

Tags: development

I understand that you can access comments in an append-only field like:

```
    public string retrieveComments(SPListItem item)
    {
        SPListItemVersionCollection versions = item.Versions;
        string latestComment = "";

        try
        {
            foreach (SPListItemVersion itemVersion in versions)
            {
                if (itemVersion.IsCurrentVersion)
                {
                    latestComment = itemVersion["Comments"].ToString().Trim();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e3)
        {
            //handles exception
        }

        return latestComment;
    }
```

Is there any way to create a new version of the list item and append a comment as the latest comment through C#?

My goal is for someone to email the list and take the body of their email and append it as a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to go through the Versions to get the latest value. That's the current value:

```
item["Comments"].ToString().Trim();
```

To add a new comment just update the item:

```
item["Comments"] = "This is now the latest comment";
item.Update();
```

Comment: Wow. I honestly thought I tried this already. Thanks so much.

Would up-vote but I don't have enough rep!

Comment: Is there a way to add an image attachment as a comment if the user say, sends a screenshot?

Comment: Handled it for you, cbrad.

Comment: Thanks rjcup3, easy answer apparently, but well deserved. Been stuck on this for awhile.

Comment: You can add the image as a standard attachment and then in the comments field have an `<img>` element pointing to it like:  `item["Comments"]="Comment with image: <img src='/Lists/TestList/Attachments/2/Test.png' />. Nice";`. In this case it's item with ID and the Attachment is named "Test.png"

Comment: I tried looking it up to answer it for you and I couldn't find anything. Per Jakobsen is the man though and apparently just knew it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
 List<Message> msgs = new List<Message>
            {
                new Message{Comments=new List<string>{"AS"},IsCurrent=false},
                new Message{Comments=new List<string>{"ASfff"},IsCurrent=true},
            };

            var ress = msgs.Where(ms => ms.IsCurrent); 


            foreach (var ms in ress)
            {
                ms.Comments.Add("Hello");
            }
```

Comment: I could be wrong but doesn't that just get the latest comment? I want to be able to append a comment as the latest comment.

Comment: Means if the comment is IsCurrentVersion then what you wana do ?

Comment: I want to add a comment, not retrieve them.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I will give this a try today, thanks.

Comment: How would I go about creating the Message class?

Answer (score 0):

Posted this on sharepoint.stackexchange.com

The answer is simple (which makes me look stupid), and I'm pretty sure I tried it before with no avail, but here it is:

[Can you add comments to an append-only field in a list in Sharepoint 2010 using C#?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42164/can-you-add-comments-to-an-append-only-field-in-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using)